# Selenium web element - get element id and iterate in a loop

Tags: selenium, loops

I have these elements:

```
<div class="order-tableview__row no-outline" tabindex="-1" role="button" data-testid="table-row-1">

<div class="order-tableview__row no-outline" tabindex="-1" role="button" data-testid="table-row-2">

<div class="order-tableview__row no-outline" tabindex="-1" role="button" data-testid="table-row-3">
```

and etc. testid="table-row-**n**"

How can I get the table-row id and use it in a loop after that?

Thank you!

Comment: What language do you use? Java? Python? C#? What do you want to do in a loop?

Comment: Preferably PHP, but any language will do.
I want to use each element in another loop and get its text.

Comment: Isn't cruisepandey's answer good enough? What is missing for you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below xpath :

```
//div[@data-testid]
```

this should represent all the nodes with `data-testid` which has id as 1, 2, 3.

and if you want to use loops :

the below code is in python :

```
for etc in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid]"):
    print(etc.get_attribute('data-testid'))
    print(etc.text)
```